# Integral help needed

Tags: integration, derivatives

I'm a Calc I student trying to understand my homework. What are the steps to figure out this below? The correct answer is 2/x^5.

[image]

It would be helpful if explained in a method a Calc I student would understand.

Comment: Google the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: There is a typo in the problem, or a serious error. The integral does not exist.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry - I hadn't noticed that it diverges.

Comment: If we use the Cauchy Principal Value, it will be OK. But that is not the default interpretation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andre Nicolas points out, the improper integral
$$\int_0^{x^2}\frac{1}{t^3}\,dt$$ diverges.
 If the lower limit were say, $1$, then we could do the following calculation.

Let $u=x^2$.
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_1^{x^2}\frac{1}{t^3}\,dt=\left(\frac{d}{du}\int_1^u\frac{1}{t^3}\,dt\right)\cdot \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{u^3}(2x)=\frac{1}{(x^2)^3}(2x)=\frac{2}{x^5}$$

Comment: There was a typo, it should have been 1 but I copied it down as a zero. No wonder I stressed over this for hours!